# Getting Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null when I implement ngAfterViewInit

Tags: angular, typescript, hook

I'm trying to show a Google Map which gets the place_id from an html value.

**activity-details.page.html**

```
                    <ion-col>
                        <div id="map"></div>
                        <div *ngIf="activities">
                        <input type="hidden" id="place_id" value="{{ activities.place_id }}" />
                        </div>
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
```

This is the code returned in the browser.

```
<input _ngcontent-irr-c150="" type="hidden" id="place_id" value="ChIJ21P2rgUrTI8Ris1fYjy3Ms4">
```

I'm trying to set the map options as the last thing after all the code has loaded.

**activity-details.page.ts**

```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.geocodePlaceId(
      this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(),
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("map") as HTMLElement,
        {
          zoom: 8,
        }
      ),
      this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow());
  }
```

The issue starts when get I the place_id value from the HTML in this last function.

**activity-details.page.ts**

```
geocodePlaceId(
    geocoder: google.maps.Geocoder,
    map: google.maps.Map,
    infowindow: google.maps.InfoWindow
  ) {
    const placeId = (document.getElementById("place_id") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    geocoder.geocode({ placeId: placeId }, (results, status) => {
      ...//the rest of the options set up for the map
  }
```

I keep getting. ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the output when you run `document.getElementById("place_id").getAttribute('value');` in browser console?

Comment: It returns the value of the place_id correctly ChIJ21P2rgUrTI8Ris1fYjy3Ms4.

Comment: Then change `const placeId = (document.getElementById("place_id") as HTMLInputElement).value;` to `const placeId = document.getElementById("place_id").getAttribute('value');`

Comment: I tried to replace it with your document.getElementById etc. but it shows the error. Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null

Comment: Meaning `document.getElementById("place_id")` returns as a `null`. Try moving code to another lifecycle hook like after content init.

Comment: Still same issue. I've changed the code to the ngAfterContentInit hook.

Answer (score 0):

Add an if condition so that you want have to worry about errors

```
geocodePlaceId(
    geocoder: google.maps.Geocoder,
    map: google.maps.Map,
    infowindow: google.maps.InfoWindow
  ) {
    const placeId = (document.getElementById("place_id") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    if (placeId) {
        geocoder.geocode({ placeId: placeId }, (results, status) => {
            ...//the rest of the options set up for the map
        }
    }

   // So whats happening is, placeId is not getting a value and even before you get it, you are setting it in the geocoder.geocode line. Wait for the value to come and then set it.
```

Comment: Hello Srikar! I'm getting the same issue mentioned above.